# Timer service EJB 3.0 vs EJB 3.1

Tags: java, jboss, timer, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

In my current project I need to create one periodic re-occurring Batch job.
Previously I have used custom framework to implement this. Now looking into EJB Timer Service API.

What is the best way to implement Timer Service and deploy in JBoss AS (v4.2). What is the difference in EJB 3.0/3.1 with respect to implementation of Timer.

JBoss also providing scheduler but I don't have much idea about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Jboss 4.2(.3) you can use EJB 3.0 timers but they are not very powerful.

If you need powerful scheduling rules (similar to unix cron) use quartz: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org

This links should give you a start into this:

http://www.len.ro/2008/10/another-way-to-use-quartz-in-jboss/

EJB 3.1 timers are more powerful, for example you can declaratively specify cron like scheduling rules, but they are not available by default in jboss 4.2(.3)